# IOS crash report

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, appcelerator, symbolicatecrash

I have device logs crash report from iPhone  .How to find the exact reason from my crash report. IOS version 8.3 This is not a reproducible crash.It occurs rarely and no specific senario. Pelase help me to find out.I have build this IOS app in appcelerator platform.

```
Incident Identifier: 3DCFCFFB-4F05-4F88-B227-21C6BEF1066A
CrashReporter Key:   a01734574dac253357853c43788d42f540be2749
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             CAST [320]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A78C6B56-1ED0-4D07-8857-B3D154779EBF/CAST.app/CAST
Identifier:          com.ca.tridentapp
Version:             1.2.1.0 (1.2.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-05-31 12:26:54.357 +0530
Launch Time:         2016-05-31 11:59:41.463 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18224c2d8 0x182124000 + 1213144
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193a700e4 0x193a68000 + 32996
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18224bc8c 0x182124000 + 1211532
3   CAST                            0x1000e6988 -[TiApp flushCompletionHandlerQueue] (TiApp.m:569)
4   CAST                            0x1000e7d4c -[TiApp applicationWillEnterForeground:] (TiApp.m:911)
5   UIKit                           0x186ef9f48 0x186c7c000 + 2613064
6   UIKit                           0x186f256fc 0x186c7c000 + 2791164
7   UIKit                           0x186f24dfc 0x186c7c000 + 2788860
8   UIKit                           0x186f24d54 0x186c7c000 + 2788692
9   UIKit                           0x186f17fe0 0x186c7c000 + 2736096
10  FrontBoardServices              0x18aa553c8 0x18aa3c000 + 103368
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18220427c 0x182124000 + 918140
12  CoreFoundation                  0x182203384 0x182124000 + 914308
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1822019a8 0x182124000 + 907688
14  CoreFoundation                  0x18212d2d4 0x182124000 + 37588
15  GraphicsServices                0x18b9436fc 0x18b938000 + 46844
16  UIKit                           0x186cf2fac 0x186c7c000 + 487340
17  CAST                            0x100022aec main (main.m:37)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x1940eea08 0x1940ec000 + 10760


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194207270 0x1941ec000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942a516c 0x1942a0000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019417eb14 0x19411c000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019323d414 0x19323c000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019325cb88 0x19323c000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193a703bc 0x193a68000 + 33724
6   CAST                            0x00000001005bf7f4 CPPExceptionTerminate() (KSCrashSentry_CPPException.mm:193)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193259bb0 0x19323c000 + 121776
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193259738 0x19323c000 + 120632
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193a70290 0x193a68000 + 33424
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018212d380 0x182124000 + 37760
11  GraphicsServices                0x000000018b9436f8 0x18b938000 + 46840
12  UIKit                           0x0000000186cf2fa8 0x186c7c000 + 487336
13  CAST                            0x0000000100022ae8 main (main.m:37)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001940eea04 0x1940ec000 + 10756
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would suggest to use https://get.fabric.io/ios or https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack for log / error reports

Comment: Crashlytics will help you.

Comment: It's giving you a source file name and line number.  What does the code in that area look like?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you can do two things:

- You could integrate a 3rd party crash reporting library such as [Instabug](https://instabug.com) which will help you get more details about the type of device, software version, CPU load, memory usage, and connectivity. All of which are important factors when it comes to debugging and reproducing the crash.
- The crash report is not symbolicated. You first have to locate your project’s dSYM file. Type the line below in terminal so you can locate the file.

  ```
  mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == your-UUID-here"
  ```

  You can find your UUID written on top of the Instabug dashboard.
  You can then upload your dSYM file through the dashboard to get symbolicated crashes that are more comprehensible.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.